# InnoDB tablespace id error

Tags: mysql, innodb

Good day everyone!

So yesterday my computer froze while I had MySQL running. I don't recall there being any transactions going on—I just use it for some development.

Today, I try to access one of the databases, afl_discounts, I've been working on, and I realize that it can't 'describe' any of my tables; in fact, the only thing I seem to be able to do is list the tables and anything else just spits out:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'afl_discounts.users' doesn't exist.
```

or something similar. I check the error log around the same time that my computer froze:

```
2014-08-02 23:18:10 260 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-08-02 23:18:10 260 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-08-02 23:18:10 260 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-08-02 23:18:11 260 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-08-02 23:18:11 260 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2014-08-02 23:18:11 7fff74dc7310  InnoDB: Error: table 'afl_discounts/companies'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 20,
InnoDB: but the tablespace with that id has name AFL_Discounts/companies.
InnoDB: Have you deleted or moved .ibd files?
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
```

It says this for every table in that one database, everything else seemed okay—i even used mysqlcheck. I referred to the link and I'm a little lost. Also, notice that the id names in the conflict really only differ by case. What's the best way to deal with this? Have I totally messed up my database?

Oh, I'm running OSX 10.9, MySQL 5.6.19.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: mysqlcheck is irrelevant here because it works with MyISAM tables while yours are InnoDB. It looks to me that your MySQL instance was up and running for a while, but some time ago ibdata1 was removed by some external command. After MySQL restarted InnoDB closed ibdata1 and filesystem completely released the space used by the file. Then at start InnoDB create a new ibdata1. But of course it knows nothing about your tables. InnoDB dictionary is empty.

Comment: @akuzminsky It is relevant: According to [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) mysqlcheck uses some of the commands found in mysqld to do it's work, one of which is 'CHECK TABLE', which works on InnoDB tables. It will not however, repair the database if there's a problem.

Comment: Maybe you tell us what *exactly* CHECK TABLE does with InnoDB table? Just to understand what "works" means. :)

Comment: I couldn't tell you, but I do trust the documentation. If I'm incorrect in my statements please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So,

I did a chmod on the folders that hold the .ibd files and noticed that the permissions were off—700 
(drwx------). Why this was the case is anyone's guess, but after running chmod 755 (drwxr-xr-x) on the 'afl_discounts' folder and running mysqlcheck, everything reported 'OK'. The database works.

If anyone can give an idea as to why this happened I'd greatly appreciate it.